# Koala always get Koala::Facebook::ServerError when i add args hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

when I do this:

```
graph.put_wall_post("test",{name: "test_post",link: LINK_URL})
```

I have an error:

```
*** Koala::Facebook::ServerError Exception: type: OAuthException, code: 2, message: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later. [HTTP 500]
```

Comment: so you can read, but can't write?

Comment: solved! and thanks for your revision @majioa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!

The problem is URL from LINK_URL variable blocked by facebook. I think too many tests to use that URL during the development.

when i try use another URL its work!

Comment: <downvote> This makes absolutely no sense, what was the value of `FB_URL` that was blocked and what change fixed it for you?

Comment: "absolutely no sense?" i really appreciate if you try first before argues, FB_URL value 'staging.xxxxxx.com' (during the development), blocked because I do a lot of post during the development. i just change url for staging development to 'appdev.xxxxxx.com'

Comment: So are you saying that your Application's URL was misconfigured? You updated it in `developer.facebook.com`?

Comment: that is not about Application's URL, URL i mean is url parameter on post, example to create post contains a link to timeline:

"Hi bla bla bla bla bla, go to http://staging.myapp.com for more info",

i mean that link => http://staging.myapp.com

Comment: Can you edit your answer to reflect this?
I will withdraw my downvote.

Comment: what should be update? the question is `graph.put_wall_post("test",{name: "test_post",link: FB_URL})` that is code for put post, with link argument (FB_URL). the answer about FB_URL variable

Comment: ahh i see.. FB_URL is unclear variable name, LINK_URL will more clearly :)